# Why Samsung Galaxy Ace GT-S5830i shows only a battery icon instead of booting?

Tags: battery, samsung-galaxy-ace

I've got a used Samsung Galaxy Ace GT-S5830i smartphone - it had basically no issues, but when I attempted to turn on (it was charged almost all night), what appeared is only a battery icon with no boot.

It has already happened some times before, but in those cases, taking out battery and putting back always solved the case.

This time, it didn't. What's the possible reason and how can I fix it?

(if that matters, the mini-USB end of the cable I use for the charger also has some issues, with only making proper contact in some certain positions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either your battery has failed (internal connection failure or shorted cell), or the battery contacts in the phone are no longer making contact with the battery terminals.  Most smart phones (including Samsung models, in my experience) will refuse to boot until the battery has a certain level of charge (around 15%); and if the battery won't accept a charge for some reason, the phone will never start up.

If you can, see if the phone will work with a different battery; if so, replacing the battery will solve the problem.  Otherwise, it may be possible to rebend the contact springs, clean the contact surfaces, or otherwise restore good contact to resolve the issue.

Comment: "Otherwise, it may be possible to rebend the contact springs, clean the contact surfaces, or otherwise restore good contact to resolve the issue." And how can I do that?

Comment: I don't know that model specifically, but in my S4 (and every other phone I've had the battery out of in the past few years) the phone's battery contacts are little spring leaves.  Carefully bending them so they press a little harder on the battery terminals is the general method; specific for that phone I can't help with.

Comment: Another way that worked for me, is to fold aluminum foil into a thin strip and wedge it between the bottom of battery and casing. This pushes the Battery upwards and forces connection

Comment: @beeshyams That's a good way to check if battery contact is the issue, and may be useful longer term if the contacts aren't accessible to adjust, but it carries a hazard of the foil strip getting loose when you have the battery out and, if you don't notice it before reinserting the battery, potentially shorting the battery (possibly leading to a fire or explosion).  At the least, I'd use something non-conductive, like a layer or two of masking tape on the non-terminal end of the battery.

Comment: You are right. I should have clarified. Aluminum foil I used was the food wrapping type, which has a butter paper surface on the other side, so that can be used..but yes as you pointed out, long term risk is still there..thanks

Comment: @ZeissIkon thanks! Strangely however, when I took out the battery, left separated for an hour or so, and then I put it back, the phone worked perfectly. Any ideas, why?

Comment: @ZoltánSchmidt That *may* be a safety feature in the phone's firmware: if it decides the connected battery is bad, the phone may refuse to enter a high-draw mode (like starting up the full OS) to prevent a battery fire.  I'm not certain that's the case, but if it is, leaving the battery out for an extended time is likely to reset it, and a bad connection at the terminals could cause the "bad battery" detection in the first place.